# Undesired behaviour on iterating with list of dictionary in python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

So I have this **`results`** variable containing list of objects. So i write this code

```
entry = {}
temp = []
temp2 = []
for result in results:
    entry['value'] = result['fb_id']
    entry['label'] = result['full_name']

    temp.append(entry)
    temp2.append(result)

    print (result)
    print (entry)

print temp
print temp2
```

This prints

```
{'fb_id': 17500787L, 'full_name': u'Sandipan Mondal'}  #this is result1
{'value': 17500787L, 'label': u'Sandipan Mondal'}      #this is entry1
{'fb_id': 597333664L, 'full_name': u'Aakash Tulsani'}  #this is result2
{'value': 597333664L, 'label': u'Aakash Tulsani'}      #this is entry2

[{'value': 597333664L, 'label': u'Aakash Tulsani'},       #this is temp
{'value': 597333664L, 'label': u'Aakash Tulsani'}]

[{'fb_id': 17500787L, 'full_name': u'Sandipan Mondal'},   #this is temp2
{'fb_id': 597333664L, 'full_name': u'Aakash Tulsani'}
```

Now **`temp2`** variable comes out to be as expected i.e. **`[result1, result2]`** but that's not happening with **`temp`** variable.
It is repeating **`entry2`**

Comment: Move `entry = {}` inside the for-loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you're overwriting the contents of `entry` at every iteration. This means that you keep a list of references in the list `temp` to the *same* dictionary `entry` and keep appending this dictionary over and over again. Reset the dictionary at each iteration:

```
for result in results:
    entry = {}

    entry['value'] = result['fb_id']
    entry['label'] = result['full_name']

    temp.append(entry)
    temp2.append(result)

    print (result)
    print (entry)
```

You don't need the `temp2` at all, as you already have your results in the `results` list you're iterating. So just use that. As for the converted entries, if you hold a key mapping for the conversion, you can do something like this:

```
>>> m = {'fb_id': 'value', 'full_name': 'label'}
>>> [{m[k]: v for k, v in result.iteritems()} for result in results]
[{'label': u'Sandipan Mondal', 'value': 17500787L},
 {'label': u'Aakash Tulsani', 'value': 597333664L}]
```

This uses a list and dictionary comprehension to iterate over each dictionary in results and gets the correct key for each key and value-pair from the conversion dictionary `m`.